# Sequelize Multiple Column in Clause

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a table called attribute where i need to select based on SQL IN Clause in multiple tables, How can I achieve it using Sequelize in Clause.

My Query is :

```
select * from attr where (tid, pid) in ((1, 3440), (344, 3441))
```

But in Sequelize only 1 column in is Supported.

Comment: If you are using sequelize, `attr.findAll({ where: { tid: [1,3440], pid: [344,3441] } })`

Comment: Change your query. Sometimes query can be written in many ways. Find one that can match sequelize querying habbits

Comment: @JitendraKumar ok how will you rewrite this in sequelize (pubdate, feedItemId) < ($1, $2)